# Logastash CSV Filter|Convert

Tags: csv, logstash, elastic-stack

facing a problem with converting some values from csv.
If i declare only **one** converting e.g 'id'=>'integer' it works fine.
If i add another converting like in the config below it crashes....

```
    input {
        tcp {
            port => 5000
        }
        file {
              path => '/tmp/logstash/databases/1.csv'
              type => 'test'
              start_position => 'beginning'
          }
    }

    filter {
        csv {
            columns => ['Id','ElapsedRealTimeNanos','Accuracy','Altitude','Bearing','CreatedOn','Latitude','Longitude','Provider','Speed','Time']
            separator => ','
            convert => {'Accuracy' => 'float','id'=>'integer'}
        }
    }

    output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => 'elasticsearch:9200'
        }
        stdout{

        }
    }
```

Error:

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-04-27T18:49:51.881000+0000", 
:message=>"fetched an invalid config", 
:config=>"input {\n\ttcp {\n\t\tport => 5000\n\t}\n\tfile {\n 
path => '/tmp/logstash/databases/1.csv'\n          
type => 'test'\n          start_position => 'beginning'\n 
}\n}\n\nfilter {\n    csv {\n        
columns => ['Id','ElapsedRealTimeNanos','Accuracy','Altitude','Bearing','CreatedOn','Latitude','Longitude','Provider','Speed','Time']\n        
separator => ','\n\t\t\t\tconvert => {'Accuracy' => 'float','id'=>'integer'}\n    }\n}\n\noutput {\n\telasticsearch {\n\t\t\thosts => 'elasticsearch:9200'\n\t}\n\tstdout{\n\n\t}\n}\n\n", 
:reason=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 16, column 38 (byte 391) after filter {\n    csv {\n       
columns => ['Id','ElapsedRealTimeNanos','Accuracy','Altitude','Bearing','CreatedOn','Latitude','Longitude','Provider','Speed','Time']\n        
separator => ','\n\t\t\t\tconvert => {'Accuracy' => 'float'", :level=>:error}
```

Comment: UPDATE: converting it with mutate works!

Answer (score -1):

You can use it as:

```
...
convert => {
    'Accuracy' => 'float'
    'Id' => 'integer'
}
...
```

without a comma between conversions.

You can also use ----configtest option to check your config file for errors:

```
λ bin/logstash -f example.conf --configtest
```

Comment: thanks alpert - not error anymore. But unfortunately the strings get not converted :/ the accuracy is saved as e.g. 30.0

Comment: to be more clear: within kibana it shows "string" as type for accuracy

Comment: Delete index and index template created by logstash. Remove header form csv. It creates number format exception. Reindex your data. That worked for me. Also `id` must be `Id`.